# How to find the sum of all numbers in a selected listForm C#

Tags: c#

I have a `ListForm` in `C#`
The question is when a user clicks on a certain student in the list I want it to find the average, score count and sum.
Code Below:

```
private void listForm1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtTotal.Text = listForm1.SelectedItem.ToString();
}


private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listForm1.Items.Add("Hamish overtonne" + "|" + 39 + "|" + 12 + "|" + 85);
    listForm1.Items.Add("Claudia Dye" + "|" + 44 + "|" + 56 + "|" + 85);
    listForm1.Items.Add("Mike Layne" + "|" + 12 + "|" + 47+ "|" + 28);
}
```

That's All I have for now

Comment: Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Fixed apologise first time using this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code you can use to do that. Just keep in mind to register a `SelectedIndexChanged` event to your list.

Also keep in mind that using integers, like I did, will create whole numbers, without decimal points.

I've added code comments to explain the process:

```
private void listForm1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the value from the selected item
    string val = listForm1.GetItemText(listForm1.SelectedItem);

    // Split the item's value to a string array according to the pipe char
    string[] valArray = val.Split('|');

    int sum = 0;
    int scores = 0;

    // Iterate through all possible values and sum it up, 
    // while keeping count to how many numbers there are:
    for (int i = 1; i < valArray.Length; i++)
    {
          int num = Convert.ToInt32(valArray[i]);
          sum += num;
          scores++;
    }

    // Calculate the  average. 
    // Keep in mind using an integer will create a whole number, without decimal points.        
    int average = sum / scores;

    // Place the average and the sum in textboxes
    txtAverage.Text = average.ToString();
    txtTotal.Text = sum.ToString();
    txtCount.Text = scores.ToString();
}
```

Comment: In this registry, a user can add as many numbers to a Student as they like as well as how do we get the count of all the numbers the user puts in?

Comment: Also, Value at the end of selected item does not exist?

Comment: string val = listForm1.SelectedItem.Value; says Value does not contain a definition and in the for loop, it says invalid expression on the second int (int i = 1; int < valArray.Length; i++)

Comment: listForm1.SelectedItem.Value; The .Value still errors

Comment: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value'  accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found.

Comment: what is the control called EXACTLY? there is no such control called "ListForm".

Comment: This comes up when i double click the list box on my form

Comment: so it's a list box, not list form. See updated answer, use `string val = listForm1.GetItemText(listForm1.SelectedItem);`

Comment: Apologies again how would I now count all the scores that a student has keeping in mind that it could be endless?

Comment: how do I make it display in my txtcount?

Comment: Is there a chat we can go to that is more consistent as I have some further questions? Or is it a better choice to ask here again when the time is ready?

Comment: you can ask here.

Comment: Oh the tick? is that what u mean

Comment: Done :D Mister Koby Thankyou for your help

Comment: Koby, I have a new issue whenever I try to delete a person from the registry
it comes up with an error saying "Attempted to divide by zero"
Code Below:
 for (int v = 0; v < listForm1.SelectedItems.Count; v++)
            {
                listForm1.Items.Remove(listForm1.SelectedItems[v]);
            }

Comment: please post a new question and post me the link here as a comment

Answer (score -1):

try below code :

```
private void listForm1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the value from the selected item
    string val = listForm1.GetItemText(listForm1.SelectedItem);

    // Split the item's value to a string array according to the pipe char
    string[] valArray = val.Split('|');

    int sum = 0;
    int scores = 0;
    int value=0;
    // Iterate through all possible values and sum it up, 
    // while keeping count to how many numbers there are:
    for (int i = 1; i < valArray.Length; i++)
    {
int.TryParse(valArray[i], out value);
if(value>0){
          int num = value;
          sum += num;
          scores++;
}
    }

    // Calculate the  average. 
    // Keep in mind using an integer will create a whole number, without decimal points.        
    int average = sum / scores;

    // Place the average and the sum in textboxes
    txtAverage.Text = average.ToString();
    txtTotal.Text = sum.ToString();
    txtCount.Text = scores.ToString();
}
```

Comment: In SO, there are some ethics you need to follow. If you have a slight correction to make in my answer, go ahead and edit it. Copying my exact answer is unethical. Hence my downvote. I suggest removing this answer and removing your obvious downvote to my answer, which, as you can see, was 100% correct.

Comment: Indeed I agree.